# Hibernate join two entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, web-services, spring-boot, entity

i really don't know what actually my problem is.

I have two models in my Project.

model-package

- Ansprechpartner
- Lieferant

---

**Ansprechpartner.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANSPRECHPARTNER")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"anlageAm", "updatedAt"}, allowGetters = true)
public class Ansprechpartner {

...

@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "lief_code", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = "APART_LIEF_FK"))
private Lieferanten liefCode;

public Lieferanten getLiefCode() {
    return liefCode;
}

public void setLiefCode(Lieferanten liefCode) {
    this.liefCode = liefCode;
}

...

}
```

---

**Lieferant.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LIEFERANTEN")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"anlageAm"}, allowGetters = true)
public class Lieferanten {

...

@Id
private String code;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "liefCode")
private Set<Ansprechpartner> apart;


public String getCode() {
    return code;
}


public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public Set<Ansprechpartner> getApart() {
    return apart;
}


public void setApart(Set<Ansprechpartner> apart) {
    this.apart = apart;
}

...

}
```

---

**My Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/apart")
public class AnsprechpartnerController {

...

@GetMapping("/all/{id}")
public Ansprechpartner getApartWithId(@PathVariable("id") long id) {

    Ansprechpartner apart = apartRepository.findOne(id);

    return apartRepository.findOne(id);
}

}
```

When i try to get the json data i get the following problem. **Ansprechpartner** gets data from **Lieferant** (because of that join). But then **Lieferant** again shows data from **Ansprechpartner** and so on.

Maybe better described with the following picture:
[Image with explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmESj.png)

---

**EDIT:**

I finally solved it with the @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation:

In my Ansprechpartner.java i did it this way:

```
    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("apart")
//  @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(
         name = "lief_code", 
         foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = "APART_LIEF_FK")
    )
    private Lieferanten liefCode;
```

And in my Lieferanten.java i did it this way:

```
//  @JsonBackReference
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("liefCode")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "liefCode", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Ansprechpartner> apart;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid infinite recursions you can use @JsonManagedReference & @JsonBackReference 
Json Infinite Recursion is one of the most common problems when we serialize Java objects which having Bidirectional-Relationships.

`@JsonManagedReference:` a part with the annotation will be serialized normally.
`@JsonBackReference:` a part with the annotation will be omitted from serialization.

like:

```
   @JsonBackReference
   private Set<Ansprechpartner> apart;
```

You can check details in [solution-2](http://javasampleapproach.com/json/resolve-json-infinite-recursion-problems-working-jackson)

Comment: Is there another way to do it? Because, if I want to access all Ansprechpartner which are under Lieferanten, it is not possible. I still want that bidirectional, but not a recursion.

Comment: ya,it is bidirectional just you have to add


`@JsonBackReference
   private Set<Ansprechpartner> apart` in Lieferant.java



`@JsonManagedReference
private Lieferanten liefCode;` in Ansprechpartner.java

Comment: Hi mjsoft, i tried it...It works for Ansprechpartner. I get the data of Ansprechpartner + related data of Lieferanten (without Recursion). But if I try to get the data of Lieferanten I don't get the related data of Ansprechpartner. The field "apart" is totally ignored. It works in one direction, but not in both :/

Comment: can you sho me your pojo

Comment: I solved my problem with JsonIgnoreProperties. I commented out the JsonBackReference and JsonManagedReference, but it's still in the code. I have edited my Question above.

Answer (score 0):

Strange behaviour. Possibly you could try:

**1)** Make sure in the `Lieferanten` entity, in the `equals` / `hashCode` you do not use the `Set<Ansprechpartner> apart`.

**2)** You can explicitly detach the entities from the persistence context:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "lief_code"
          , foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = "APART_LIEF_FK")
          , cascade={CascadeType.DETACH})
private Lieferanten liefCode;
```

and then in the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/all/{id}")
public Ansprechpartner getApartWithId(@PathVariable("id") long id) {

    Ansprechpartner apart = apartRepository.findOne(id);
    apartRepository.detach(apart);  
    return apart;
}
```

you would need to implement a bit -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795436/spring-jparepository-detach-and-attach-entity), in repository in order to have that available.

**3)** explicitly add lazy loading: `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "liefCode", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is jackson trying to serialize object when object has Bidirectional-Relationships.
You can fixed it by this way 
[Short way](http://javasampleapproach.com/json/resolve-json-infinite-recursion-problems-working-jackson)

Better way : 
Returning entities directly to view layer is not a good practice.
You should convert entities to DTOs ([Data Transfer Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)) and pass the DTOs to view

Comment: Your first solutiuon: Is there another way to do it? Because, if I want to access all Ansprechpartner which are under Lieferanten, it is not possible. I still want that bidirectional, but not a recursion. The better approach: I will try it.

Comment: Have you tried to add @JsonIgnore to the property "liefCode" (Ansprechpartner.java) ?

Comment: I solved my problem with JsonIgnoreProperties. Just @JsonIgnore would not help in my case