# How to evict an entity from a @Transactional method to prevent its persistence?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have a transaction that has to update a specific entity A, the problem is that in that same transaction, in order to get the data needed to update this entity A, it takes another entity linked to the database (Entity B).

This would be ok, but the problem is that it does not just take it, it updates entity B, so at the end of the transaction, it updates Entity A and Entity B when it should only update Entity A.

This code is very old, and the Entity B is huge in order to create a POJO or something like that to avoid editing the entity B directly.

I've been researching and I found `session.evict(instanceOfEntityB)` but the problem is that this does not seem to be working, as it is updating this entity (checking the version in the database, it changes...). So I wanted to know if there is another way to prevent Entity B from persisting.

Comment: It isn't clear the relationship on A and B and why you'd need B there to update A. Evicting (or you may be looking for the JPA EntityManager 'detach' api, not eviction) the entity won't help if there is some link from any other managed entity to B that will cause changes to be merged back in.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `entityManager.detach(yourEntity)`

> Remove the given entity from the persistence context, causing a
> managed entity to become detached. Unflushed changes made to the
> entity if any (including removal of the entity), will not be
> synchronized to the database. Entities which previously referenced the
> detached entity will continue to reference it.

Comment: Thanks! sorry for the late response, could you give me an example to see how could I implement this solution inside a @transactional method?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795436/spring-jparepository-detach-and-attach-entity