# How to copy JPA entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

How to copy entity with multiple @OneToMany?
I have entities:
*Profile.java*

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"id"})
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile")
public class Profile implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "profile", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<ProfileDoc> documents = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "profileAddress", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private AddressBirth birthPlace;

}
```

*ProfileDoc*

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
@ToString(exclude = "profile")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"id", "profile"})
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile_doc")
public class ProfileDoc implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "doc_code")
private String documentCode;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="profile_id")
private Profile profile;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<DocFile> files = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

How to copy Profile(all field) without id?
as I understand it, you need to copy documents without profile_id in ProfileDoc class
**UPD:**
I want copy entity from another entity(copy) for save to DB

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(profile, newProfile);
```

if I copy with Id, then the original entity will update, not a new one

Comment: what does you mean by copy?  can you please explain in more details your issue

Comment: see his previous question

Comment: @Jacob see UPD please

Comment: @AlexBrekhin, see this answer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625096/cloning-jpa-entity