# Copy entry of entity in JHipster

Tags: copy, jhipster

I would like to be able to copy an already existing entry of an entity in Jhipster.
As exemple this one:
[jhipster entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Isi5.png)

But I have no idea where and how to start.

Edit: Im a beginner. I have to do changes in the back- and frontend but my question is about the backend.

Comment: Your question lacks many details, which could be normal if you are a beginner. Indicating your programming level (in question or in profile) could help people to guide you to a better answer. Also, you did not indicate whether your issue is related to backend and/or frontend code. If it includes frontend then you should indicate which framework: angular, react or vue. For backend you should indicate which type of database: SQL, MongoDb or Cassandra. Please edit your question rather than adding comments.

Answer (score 1):

This have nothing to do with jhipster. You can find a similar question here : [How to clone a JPA entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625096/how-to-clone-a-jpa-entity)